# Как удалить проект на хостинге для ботов Amvera Cloud!

Tags: python, бот, discord

Помогите удалить проект на хостинге для ботов Amvera Cloud! У меня нет кнопки "Настройки" в проекте

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка "Настройки" точно есть, возможно, нужно раскрыть на десктопе на весь экран, иногда адаптив "едет". Она правее кнопок "Лог приложения" и "Лог Сборки" если в сам проект зайти.